# List item click stopped working when included a layout as an list item

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So I have a list of sounds. When I click a list item - it plays a sound. When I click a included layout which is a part of a list item it does some other action. For testing purposes, I had an image as a button. And it worked really well - i click on the list item and it plays a sound, i click the image which is a part of the list item and it does other action. When I replaced an image with a layout to be included as a list item. My click on list item eventually has stopped working. The Button works fine. Please see my layout for list item below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="64dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Imglogo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:tint="#ffa500" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="#878787"
    android:textSize="16sp" />


<include
    android:id="@+id/buttonInsideListItem"
    layout="@layout/some_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

UPDATE:

I provide java code.

I handle a button which inside a list item through adapter class:

```
View buttonInsideListItem = (View) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonInsideListItem);
    buttonInsideListItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //Some stuff I cannot reveal
        }
    });
```

I handle a list item click inside Main Activity:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
      //List item click is handled here
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Provide Java code as well.

Comment: The thing here is you use normal list view......you can use `RecyclerView` instead

Comment: Sorry. I did not.mention I use a recycler view with a custom adapter. I believe there is something wrong with xml. I just dont know what